# Taylor polynomials' plots begin to look odd in graphing software for high-degree polynomials

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, graphing-functions

I was playing around with Taylor approximations using some [graphing software](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mtr1rqh1xt). I am using $-\sin\left(x\right)\approx-x+\frac{1}{3!} x^{3}-\frac{1}{5!} x^{5}+ \ldots$.

When I turn the Taylor polynomial into a Sum notation, to make the degree of the polynomial easier to vary, I notice that, for smaller-degree polynomials (say, take $k=10$ in the link above), the plotted curve looks smooth. However, for larger $k$, say $k>50$, the plotted curve begins to show "breaks" in it, or to look "hairy" somehow.

Is this a fundamental feature of the underlying polynomial, or a computing issue of some sort?

If the former, then is the lesson here that Taylor/Maclaurin approximations about a point $x=c$ are fundamentally only good within a certain range of $c$, for any degree polynomial? E.g. if I want an approximation that's good near $x=100$, **could** I in principle calculate the polynomial at $x=0$ and just expand it to a high enough degree (ignoring efficiency concerns etc.)? Or at some point would I **have** to change what the starting $c$ of my polynomial was?

If this is a computing issue only, then any ideas what is happening? Because e.g. the same software has no issues in drawing the original curve $y=-\sin\left(x\right)$ for $x$ values beyond where it seems to struggle to draw the polynomial (assuming that it *is* struggling). So how is it drawing the sine curve in the first place, if not by computing a polynomial approximation?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that for the $\sin$ function, the individuals terms may get very large before getting small.  Since the signs alternate, you're trying to compute a small number by subtracting two large numbers, which means that you end up computing the round-off error.  In general, it's best to use a Taylor expansion about a point close the values at which you want to approximate the function.  As for the computation of $\sin x$ in the graphing program, no doubt the programmer of the math library knew that $\sin$ is periodic.

Comment: What's the software? With Wolfram Mathematica there is no such problem. I suspect that the software you are using does not handle well the underflow errors that will occur in the higher order terms.

Comment: Hi, the link is [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mtr1rqh1xt). Cheers,

Comment: For what ranges of $x$? For the sine series for terms up to degree $51,$ the derivative has at most $25$ positive zeroes, and for small $|x|$ the derivative will closely approximate $\cos x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl; dr: It's the latter, a numerical issue.

An absolutely convergent power series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k}(x - x_{0})^{k}
$$
has the pleasant property that for every positive integer $n$, and for $|x - x_{0}| \leq |R|$,
$$
\biggl|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} a_{k}(x - x_{0})^{k}\biggr|
\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} |a_{k}|\, |x - x_{0}|^{k}
\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} |a_{k}| |R|^{k}.
$$
Consequently, if the series converges absolutely at a point $x_{0} + R$, then the tails dominate the convergence on $[x_{0} - |R|, x_{0} + |R|]$.

Since the sine, cosine, and exponential series have infinite radius, they converge absolutely for all real (or complex) $x$. This has two implications for your question:

1. For each real $x$, you can approximate $\sin x$ as closely as you like with some Taylor polynomial centered at $x_{0} = 0$.
2. For a Taylor polynomial in 1., the approximation is at least as good on $[-|x|, |x|]$ as it is at $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Any polynomial $p(x)$ of high degree goes very rapidly to $\pm \infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$, so it can only be a good approximation of a bounded function on a certain interval, and outside that interval it will typically grow very rapidly.  That interval grows as the degree of the Taylor polynomial increases: since $\sin$ is an entire function, it eventually grows arbitrarily large.

Here is an animation of $\sin(x)$ and its Taylor approximations of degree up to $39$.

[image]

Comment: "it eventually grows arbitrarily large" - sorry, do you mean that the value of the function gets arbitrarily large, or that the width of the interval over which it is a good approximation does?

Comment: @s7eqx9f74nc4 The width of the interval.